# IDEs and development tools for Omap 5912

Tags: c, ide, embedded

I've got one Omap5912 board and I'm willing to do some coding for practice in my spare time. I did google for some IDEs and dev tools but apart from TI Code Composer Studio I coudn't find anything appealing. Any suggestion?

Comment: I suggest that if no one gives you a good answer here, you go with what you have already found.

Comment: I have used "TI Code Composer Studio", it still got lots of issues but the updates have been solving many issues over the passed years. Now I can definitely recommend CCS.

Answer (score 1):

http://chickenfreighter.blogspot.com/2010/05/beginners-omap-l138-arm-tutorial.html here is one tutorial for using OMAP L138 via code composer studio hope so it will help you.